Mui Date Picker custom PickersDay
I want to add for each button of day - ID.
Its needed for automation tests and other things.
const CustomDay = (props: any) => {
    const { day } = props;
    const uniqueId = `day-${format(day, 'yyyy-MM-dd')}`; // unique ID for each day
    return (
      <div id={uniqueId} key={uniqueId}>
        <PickersDay {...props} day={day} />
      </div>
    );
  };

And then added as a slot to DatePicker
slots={{ day: CustomDay }}
But after this i need to click twice and super fast in order to select a date. What i am doing wrong and how i can add IDs to PickersDay component?

The error was very simple my Custom component was declared inside of the component, so after I moved the code to a separate file/component it works.
